"Required part 'assuranceRequest' is not present" when Sending JSON and Files from React Native Expo
I am trying the consume a Spring Boot endpoint that accepts 2 @RequestParts an object and a list of MultipartFiles.
I tried both axios and fetch with no results.
This is the endpoint
    @PostMapping(value = "addassurance")
    public ResponseEntity<?>  addAssurance(@RequestPart AssuranceRequest assuranceRequest, @RequestPart List<MultipartFile> assurancePapers){
         Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<>();
         Boolean result= assuranceService.addAssurance(assuranceRequest,assurancePapers);
         if(!result) {
             response.put("message","couldnt add the assurance request");
             return ResponseEntity.status(412).body(response);
         }else{ 
            response.put("message","request added successfully");             return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
         }      
}  

and this is the React Native function
export const publishAssurance = async (
  numBull,
  amount,
  matricule,
  attachs
) => {
  const json = {
    numBull: numBull,
    amount: amount,
    status: "pas pris",
    assurer: { matricule: matricule },
  };

  blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(json)], {
    type: "application/json",
  });

  console.log(JSON.stringify(json))

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("assuranceRequest",blob);

  attachs.forEach((file) => {
    formData.append("assurancePapers", file);
  });
  console.log(formData);
  try {
    let res = await fetch(HostIp + "/api/v1/assurance/addassurance", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    });

    let responseJson = await res.json();
    console.log(responseJson);

    if (res.status === 200) {
      console.log("Request added successfully");
    } else {
      console.log("Failed to add request:", responseJson.message);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error uploading assurance request:", error);
  }
};

and this is what the Spring Boot console shows
2024-07-30T12:10:02.107+01:00  WARN 22900 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required part 'assuranceRequest' is not present.]

i tried many solutions that i found on stackoverflow without a result.
changing the json to blob and indicating its type, adding the content type header to the request. but still it didnt work
